# HoloEverywhere: PreferenceFramework not found

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

I've got an error after installing HOLO to my working project.
HoloEverywhere: PreferenceFramework not found
How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following link for your solution! It says that you have to add the Preferences addon!

[Preferences Issue](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/398)

Comment: to project or to holo?

Comment: when adding it, it appears a red exclamation sign on project